# C++ Segmentation Fault caused by global variable in separate source file

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I'm a c++ noob trouble shooting for 4 hours now.  I am getting my first segmentation fault.  I think it is coming from the variable data.  The program pulls the html (using cURL) from a webpage but seg faults after fetching some HTML.  I am calling "curlbar::getThreads();" from main.cpp.  The code worked fine when it was all in main.cpp, but when I put it into curlbar, I got the segfault (core dumped) error:

```
/*
* curlbar.cpp
*
*  Created on: Feb 2, 2014
* 
*/
//get list of threads
#include "headers.h"
class curlbar{
public:
string data;
size_t writeContents(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up){
        for(unsigned int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++){
            this->data.push_back(buf[c]);
        }
        return size*nmemb;
}

static void getThreads(){

    CURL* curl;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.somewebsiteblahblah.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &curlbar::writeContents);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L); //tell curl to output its progress
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
};
```

Is the "string data;" not have enough memory allocated to it?  How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is what you're missing. you can't pass a member function as a callback, as the caller has no clue how to appropriately push `this` as the first parameter.

But you *can* do this:

```
class curlbar
{
private:
    // callback version used for curl-write-function
    static size_t writeContents_s(char *buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *up)
    {
        curlbar* pThis = static_cast<curlbar*>(up);
        return pThis->writeContents(buf, size, nmemb);
    }

public:
    std::string data;

    // member version
    size_t writeContents(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
    {
        std::copy(buf, buf+(size*nmemb), std::back_inserter(data));
        return size*nmemb;
    }

    void getThreads()
    {
        CURL* curl;
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        curl = curl_easy_init();

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.somewebsiteblahblah.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &curlbar::writeContents_s);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this); // NOTE ADDITION
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L); //tell curl to output its progress
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }
};
```

Given a `curlbar obj;` object, you invoke it as

```
curlbar obj;
obj.getThreads();
```

**How It Works**

This uses the user-defined data parameter option of an easy-curl handle to establish the piece-o-data that will be send back along with your *static* writer-callback. That data is provided as the `void *up` parameter to the callback. So we pass the pointer `this` and in the static callback use a `static_cast` to give us an object pointer, `pThis`. We use that pointer to fire the *member* function of a similar name, but no longer needing the `up` param.

Comment: I found it easier to re-write the callback function to write to a file using fwrite()... I re-wrote a lot of the part.

I did try your solution and it did compile (but I forget why I didn't use it, it's been a week).  Thank you!

(Also, Valgrind is great for finding seg-faults)