# Creating a C++ class to read data from a website to a string using libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am using http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=781021 as a guide for how to write a c++ program that use libcurl to check a website and downloads the text to a c++ app.  When I copy the code to my visual studio project, it works with only slight modification.  However, I hit a snag trying to convert it to class based files.

I created a `.h` and `.cpp` files to run the query.  What I didn't realize before was that `handle_data` was not a typical function, since it is not given any arguments or even `()` in the midway down Viewer.cpp.  This is how the above site did it, and it worked, but I'm at a loss as to why or how to convert it now.

Does anyone know whats going on here or how to fix it?
Thanks!

Viewer.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "curl.h"

class Viewer
{
public:
    Viewer(void);
    ~Viewer(void);

    std::string view(std::string q);

private:
    size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream);

    std::string contents;

};
```

Viewer.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Viewer.h"
#include <iostream>

Viewer::Viewer(void)
{
std::cout << "ViewerCreated!\n";
}


Viewer::~Viewer(void)
{
}

size_t Viewer::handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) 
{ 
    int numbytes = size*nmemb; 
    // The data is not null-terminated, so get the last character, and replace 
    // it with '\0'. 
    char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1); 
    *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0'; 
    contents.append((char *)ptr); 
    contents.append(1,lastchar); 
    *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;  // Might not be necessary. 
    return size*nmemb; 
}

std::string Viewer::view(std::string q)
{
    char* url = "www.google.com";

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init(); 
    if(curl) 
        { 
        // Tell libcurl the URL 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, url); 
        // Tell libcurl what function to call when it has data 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,handle_data); 
        // Do it! 
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
        if (res == 0) 
            std::cout << contents << std::endl; 
        else 
            std::cerr << "Error: " << res << std::endl; 
        } 

    return contents;
}
```

Comment: `handle_data` needs to be static. One example of how to do that [can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21542886/1322972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not replace the last character of the chunk that you have received. Instead you should force that the buffer containing the appended blocks has a '\0' just after the end of the data. This way it can be printed, but if you are going to store that in a file, you should just write the bytes that you have received.

This has always worked for me:

```
struct MemoryStruct chunk;
chunk.memory=NULL;
chunk.size = 0; 
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
```

And the callback:

```
struct MemoryStruct {
   char *memory;
   size_t size;
};

static void *myrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
   if(ptr)
      return realloc(ptr, size);
    else
      return malloc(size);
 }

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
   size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
   struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)data;
   mem->memory = (char *)myrealloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
   if (mem->memory) {
      memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), ptr, realsize);
      mem->size += realsize;
      mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
   }
   return realsize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

handle_data is used as a parameter for curl_easy_setopt. What that means is that you have to program what handle_data does when it receives the next data chunk (providing the data chunk is what curl will do for you).

Comment: Alright.  So is it a function that requires a `Viewer::` header? or is there a different way for me to create it so that header_data knows what to do and when to do it? I think I am missing the key functionality of header_data...

Comment: As far as I can understand, not really. I assume that curl_easy_setopt will accept any function which has the same signature (return type + arguments).

Answer (score 0):

`handle_data` is being passed to `curl_easy_setopt` as a callback function, which it will call when there's data available. Because of that, `handle_data` must be called as a static function (that is, one not receiving an object pointer, because `cURL` doesn't have one). However, you're not declaring it as static. Even if you do, you are accessing `contents` inside it, which is invalid.