# std::function.target returns null

Tags: c++, c++11, curl

I'm using cURL to download files over http. cURL requires a callback to handle data, I have a callback in my class and I'm using a combination of std::bind and std::function to create a function with the proper type.

```
size_t NetworkResource::writeFunction(char *ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void *userdata)
{
...
}

void NetworkResource::loadFunction(void)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    typedef size_t CurlCallback(char*,size_t,size_t,void*);
    auto function=std::function<CurlCallback>(std::bind(&NetworkResource::writeFunction,this,_1,_2,_3,_4)).target<CurlCallback*>();
    CURL *curl=curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode err;

    ...

    err=curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,nullptr);
    if(err!=CURLE_OK) std::cout<<curl_easy_strerror(err)<<std::endl;

    err=curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,*function);
    if(err!=CURLE_OK) std::cout<<curl_easy_strerror(err)<<std::endl;

    ...
}
```

The problem is that function is null. According to the documentation, this happens when the returned type doesn't match the target type of the function, however as far as I can tell they do match.

Comment: If this is how you're trying to turn a member-function into a static function, it isn't going to work. Is there a reason you don't `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` to pass `this` down to a static callback that forwards the call to the non-static member after unpacking the pointer? [(see similar question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542723/c-segmentation-fault-caused-by-global-variable-in-separate-source-file/21542886#21542886).

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? std::function.target returns a pointer to a function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto function = std::function<CurlCallback>(
                  std::bind(&NetworkResource::writeFunction,this,
                             _1,_2,_3,_4)).target<CurlCallback*>();
```

The `std::function` object you're constructing will be destroyed at the end of the expression above, and the variable `function` would've pointed to invalid memory, had the call to [`std::function::target`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) worked as intended. In this case, it doesn't and the function call returns `nullptr`.

This is because the target function type of the `std::function` is not the same as the type of `CurlCallback`. [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24b6ca8e4ef38427) shows a case where that call works, and one where it fails.

---

Your problem can be solved without the use of `std::function` altogether.

According to the documentation for [`curl_easy_setopt`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html), when the second argument is `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, the third argument should be a pointer to a function having the signature

```
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

The last argument `userdata` can be set via a call to [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html). Use this to pass a pointer to the `NetworkResource` instance (the `this` pointer).

As for `write_callback`, create a static member function that performs the functionality you need.

```
class NetworkResource
{
  // ...
  static size_t writeFunction(char *ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void *userdata);
};

size_t NetworkResource::writeFunction(char *ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void *userdata)
{
  // userdata points to the NetworkResource instance
  auto res = static_cast<NetworkResource *>(userdata);

  // use res and the remaining function arguments to handle the call
}

void NetworkResource::loadFunction(void)
{
    CURL *curl=curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode err;

    ...

    err=curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,&NetworkResource::writeFunction);
    if(err!=CURLE_OK) std::cout<<curl_easy_strerror(err)<<std::endl;

    err=curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,static_cast<void *>(this));
    if(err!=CURLE_OK) std::cout<<curl_easy_strerror(err)<<std::endl;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not passing an std::function to curl_easy_setopt, i'm passing a function pointer. std::function.target returns a pointer to a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

today I meet this problem, I can suggest you a solution:
here is my demo

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <thread>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <functional>
 using namespace std;

 class foo {
 public:
     virtual int sum(int a, int b) { return -1; };
 };

 class bar : public foo{
 public:
     virtual int sum(int a, int b) override;
 };

 int bar::sum(int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
 }

 int main() {
     bar *b = new bar();
     std::function<int(int, int)> f = std::bind(&bar::sum, b, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
     printf("result : %d\n", f(1, 3));
     printf("result : %s\n", f.target_type().name());
     printf("null : %d\n", (*f.target<int(int, int)>())(1, 2));
     printf("null : %d\n", f);
     return 0;
 }
```

in this demo, if you write type int(int, int) to `std::function`, like this

```
std::function<int(int, int)>
```

the return type must be null, cause `int(int, int)` is not equal to the internal type

to get the internal type of `std::function`, you should first use `target_type().name()`, like this:

```
printf("%s\n", f.target_type().name());
```

the result is:

```
St5_BindIFSt7_Mem_fnIM3barFiiiEEPS1_St12_PlaceholderILi1EES6_ILi2EEEE
```

and next, you can use `c++filt` to resolve this symbol, like this:

```
c++filt -t St5_BindIFSt7_Mem_fnIM3barFiiiEEPS1_St12_PlaceholderILi1EES6_ILi2EEEE
```

the result is :

```
std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int (bar::*)(int, int)> (bar*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>
```

the symbol above is what you should write in the `std::function<...>`, so the final code is like this:

```
int main() {
     bar *b = new bar();
     std::function<int(int, int)> f = std::bind(&bar::sum, b, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
     printf("result : %d\n", f(1, 3));
     printf("result : %s\n", f.target_type().name());
     printf("null : %d\n", (*f.target<std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int (bar::*)(int, int)> (bar*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>>())(1, 2));
     printf("null : %d\n", f);
     return 0;
 }
```